# Where is the documentation for AWS API Gateway Lambda Error Regex?

Tags: regex, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Where is the documentation for the allowable `Lambda Error Regex` values for the AWS `API Gateway`?  Are they Perl regexes?  POSIX regexes?  Something else?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integration response regexes are currently limited to Java "Pattern" style regexes. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html